# azure-functions-maven-plugin final jar missing libraries in classpath

Tags: spring-boot, maven, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I am try to deploy Java Azure function app from my local machine. My tech stack is fallows,

```
Azure Function App OS: Linux
Azure Functions Core Tools (2.0.3)
Springboot 2.6.3
spring-boot-maven-plugin 2.6.3
azure-functions-maven-plugin 1.14.3
azure-functions-java-library 1.4.2
spring-cloud-function-adapter-azure 3.2.1
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.avol.func</groupId>
    <artifactId>springcloud-eh-func</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Azure Java Functions</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.14.3</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
        <azure.functions.java.library.version>1.4.2</azure.functions.java.library.version>
        <functionAppName>poc-java-func-apsp</functionAppName>
        <resource.groupname>AvolPOCs</resource.groupname>
        <appserviceplan.name>ASP-AvolPOCs-84f2</appserviceplan.name>
        <azure.region>southcentralus</azure.region>
        <azure.subscriptionid>xxxxxx</azure.subscriptionid>
        <stagingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/azure-functions/${functionAppName}</stagingDirectory>
        <start-class>com.avol.func.SpringAppRunner</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
            <version>${azure.functions.java.library.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-azure</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-logging-logback</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.functions.java.library.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>obj</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.functions.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <subscriptionId>${azure.subscriptionid}</subscriptionId>
                    <!-- function app name -->
                    <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                    <!-- function app resource group -->
                    <resourceGroup>${resource.groupname}</resourceGroup>
                    <!-- function app service plan name -->
                    <appServicePlanName>${appserviceplan.name}</appServicePlanName>
                    <!-- function app region-->
                    <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions:-Configuration-Details#supported-regions for all valid values -->
                    <region>${azure.region}</region>
                    <!-- function pricingTier, default to be consumption if not specified -->
                    <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions:-Configuration-Details#supported-pricing-tiers for all valid values -->
                    <!-- <pricingTier></pricingTier> -->
                    <!-- Whether to disable application insights, default is false -->
                    <disableAppInsights>false</disableAppInsights>
                    <runtime>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <javaVersion>11</javaVersion>
                    </runtime>
                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                            <value>~4</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME</name>
                            <value>java</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-functions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/azure-functions/${functionAppName}
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources
                                    </directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.3</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.28.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my maven build logs,

```
$ mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------< com.avol.func:springcloud-eh-func >----------------
[INFO] Building Azure Java Functions 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ springcloud-eh-func ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\padaldl\workspace\projects\Avol-POCs\src\Java\JavaFunAppPOC\springcloud-eh-func\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ springcloud-eh-func ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ springcloud-eh-func ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 10 source files to C:\Users\padaldl\workspace\projects\Avol-POCs\src\Java\JavaFunAppPOC\springcloud-eh-func\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ springcloud-eh-func ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\padaldl\workspace\projects\Avol-POCs\src\Java\JavaFunAppPOC\springcloud-eh-func\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ springcloud-eh-func ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ springcloud-eh-func ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:copy-dependencies (copy-dependencies) @ springcloud-eh-func ---
[INFO] Copying azure-functions-java-library-1.4.2.jar to C:\Users\padaldl\workspace\projects\Avol-POCs\src\Java\JavaFunAppPOC\springcloud-eh-func\target\azure-functions\poc-java-func-apsp\lib\azure-functions-java-library-1.4.2.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.2:jar (default-jar) @ springcloud-eh-func ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\padaldl\workspace\projects\Avol-POCs\src\Java\JavaFunAppPOC\springcloud-eh-func\target\springcloud-eh-func-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- azure-functions-maven-plugin:1.14.3:package (package-functions) @ springcloud-eh-func ---
[INFO] Java home : C:/Users/padaldl/workspace/installedsws/zulu-11-azure-jdk_11.52.13-11.0.13-win_x64
[INFO] Artifact compile version : 11
[INFO]
[INFO] Step 1 of 8: Searching for Azure Functions entry points
[INFO] 2 Azure Functions entry point(s) found.
[INFO]
[INFO] Step 2 of 8: Generating Azure Functions configurations
[INFO] Generation done.
[INFO]
[INFO] Step 3 of 8: Validating generated configurations
[INFO] Validation done.
[INFO]
[INFO] Step 4 of 8: Saving host.json
[INFO] Successfully saved to C:\Users\padaldl\workspace\projects\Avol-POCs\src\Java\JavaFunAppPOC\springcloud-eh-func\target\azure-functions\poc-java-func-apsp\host.json
[INFO]
[INFO] Step 5 of 8: Saving local.settings.json
[INFO] Successfully saved to C:\Users\padaldl\workspace\projects\Avol-POCs\src\Java\JavaFunAppPOC\springcloud-eh-func\target\azure-functions\poc-java-func-apsp\local.settings.json
[INFO]
[INFO] Step 6 of 8: Saving configurations to function.json
[INFO] Starting processing function: uppercase
[INFO] Successfully saved to C:\Users\padaldl\workspace\projects\Avol-POCs\\src\Java\JavaFunAppPOC\springcloud-eh-func\target\azure-functions\poc-java-func-apsp\uppercase\function.json
[INFO] Starting processing function: assetSync
[INFO] Successfully saved to C:\Users\padaldl\workspace\projects\Avol-POCs\src\Java\JavaFunAppPOC\springcloud-eh-func\target\azure-functions\poc-java-func-apsp\assetSync\function.json
[INFO]
[INFO] Step 7 of 8: Copying JARs to staging directoryC:\Users\padaldl\workspace\projects\Avol-POCs\src\Java\JavaFunAppPOC\springcloud-eh-func\target\azure-functions\poc-java-func-apsp
[INFO] Copied successfully.
[INFO] Step 8 of 8: Installing function extensions if needed
[INFO] Extension bundle specified, skip install extension
[INFO] Successfully built Azure Functions.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:copy-resources (copy-resources) @ springcloud-eh-func ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.3:repackage (repackage) @ springcloud-eh-func ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  29.790 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-03T19:39:15+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Function App works fine in local from IntellIJ IDEA, and as well run through `mvn azure-functions:run` command.

When I run the jar using java command `java -jar <>` it fails with error No Class Definition found error.

`mvn azure-functions:deploy` succeeded without any issue, and am able to see functions created on azure, but when I trigger function it fails with 500 Internal Error.

I suspect function failing in azure due to external dependencies not added to classpath of jar. From the stackoverflow I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56878815/how-to-add-my-own-code-function-and-external-java-libraries-to-azure-function-ap/56880027), suggestion is to go with maven assembly plugin, *but my question is why should we use Assembly plugin when I am using springboot plugin?*

Answer (score 0):

Finally issue got resolved after installing *Azure Functions Core Tools* version 4.x through MSI installer on windows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash#v2

And it looks like azure functions refer `/lib` folder under staging directory when function triggers, it need not be springboot fat jar.